# Different cell depending on the cell text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following situation. I am making a weather app and I am displaying the data in cells for a period of days. I have the following structure:

Day1

Min temperature

Max temperature

Day2

Min temperature

Max temperature

Day3

Min temperature

Max temperature

etc etc...

I am also using sections and the following functions:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "minimumTemperature")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "fooMinTemperature"

    return cell!
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return  // logic for getting the heading of the section
}
```

The problem comes that the   `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

function can only return 1 cell at a time. So for example this function will get called two times now and add the minimum temperature two times. How can I add both the min and max temperatures.

Comment: Use the `indexPath` to choose the correct data.

Comment: @rmaddy So basically make a big if else inside the `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` with a different cell depending on the indexPath? (I also thought of that but I thought that there's a better way)

Comment: Where are you adding anything? I don't see it in the question.

Comment: Not necessarily a huge if else is required, a two dimensional array will suffice your purpose. it will look like ` int [10][2]`, it's not swift, hope you got it

Comment: Structure the data accordingly.you can use one array and put everything in it, or use multiple arrays. One for section headers, one for data for each section

Comment: Please add the object which represents the data source. Basically never hard-code `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRows`. *...this function will get called **twenty** times* (ten sections with two rows respectively).  Consider that `cellForRow` is called once for each cell (section and row). The `indexPath` identifies the position in the table view (and in the data source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have some array of data where each element in the array represents one day, you would use the section to pick the data for the correct day. Then you use the row to choose between min or max temperature.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "minimumTemperature") as! UITableViewCell

    let data = myArrayOfDays[indexPath.section]
    let temp = indexPath.row == 0 ? data.minimumTemp : data.maximumTemp
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(temp)"

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return myArrayOfDays.count
}
```

The variable names I used are clearly just examples. Update with your own as needed.

Your section header can show the day number.